# Rake vs Rails in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rake, rake-task

1. What is the difference between commands `rake` and `rails` in Ruby?
2. Which one is faster and why?
3. Is `rails` duplicate command for `rake`?
4. Can `rails` can be used for all tasks performed by `rake` or there is any limitation?

Answer (score 3):

`rake` allows you to run rakefiles (akin to makefiles).

Previously some commands were implemented as rake tasks and some were separate scripts. Hence some could be ran with `rake` and some with `rails`.

With RoR 5 the team agreed that this is an unnecessary complexity for newcomers and made it so all rails related rake commands could also be run with `rails`.

So in short:

1. All rails related stuff that can be run with `rake` can also be ran with `rails`.
2. Not all rails related stuff that can be run with `rails` can also be ran with `rake`.
3. In terms of performance the difference is non-existent.

Hence - run everything rails related using `rails` and run rake tasks that you've defined yourself (if there are any) using `rake`.

Comment: @muhammad - `rails` commands are like `rake` tasks, but only for rails.